# Can I execute a specified task on "Format Document"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format, ide, task

I am using a custom script to format my code. Currently, whenever I want to format, I have to call `Tasks: Run Task` and then choose my format task.

**Is it possible to tell Format Document to execute my tasks?**

This would be nice because it would allow me to do automatic formation on save.

About my VSCode:

```
Version: 1.44.2
Commit: ff915844119ce9485abfe8aa9076ec76b5300ddd
Date: 2020-04-16T17:50:03.709Z
Electron: 7.1.11
Chrome: 78.0.3904.130
Node.js: 12.8.1
V8: 7.8.279.23-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-96-generic snap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it with an actual formatter but you can call tasks from keybindings.  try

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+f",
  "command": "-editor.action.formatDocument",
  "when": "editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorHasDocumentFormattingProvider && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
},

{
  "key": "shift+alt+f",         // or whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
  "args": "your format task label here"
},
```

I used the default `Format Document` keybinding but you could use whatever keybinding you wish.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it tomorrow.

Comment: It kindof works. I will mark this question as resolved, even though the solution is not ideal. Might also be, because my tasks is too slow. Not sure

Comment: Either way: Thanks! :)

Comment: What doesn't it do?

Comment: It is just very slow. But again, my guess is that this is because of my script. So everything good. Thanks again for the help :)